# Adding input accessory view to UITextField while keyboard is visible

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uitextfield

I would like to add an input accessory view to a `UITextField` while it is the first responder, i.e. showing the keyboard. Apparently, assigning a `UIView` to the `inputAccessoryView` property in this state doesn't display this view. I have to first dismiss the keyboard and re-select the `UITextField`.

Is there a way to add an input accessory view without dismissing and re-selecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If possible only assign the `inputAccessoryView` once. If you need it to be customized, and can only determine how very late just before becoming the first responder, then I would still only assign it once. But customize the subviews of the `inputAccessoryView` in the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`. Like so:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self setupInputAccessoryViewForTextField:textField];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use reloadInputViews on the textView to do that

(I know this is an old post but might help to others)

Comment: this should be checked answer

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted an input accessory view added/removed dynamically.
I ended up simply doing this:

```
[self.responceTextView resignFirstResponder];
self.responceTextView.inputAccessoryView = keyBoardToolbar;
[self.responceTextView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: that messes up keyboard behavior.

Comment: Not for me it doesn't. Maybe you should start a question with the code your using.

Comment: My problem is not solvable at all without private APIs (I found a workaround though). But, your code let my keyboard jerk around when in undocked mode. That might be related to textview listeners, but still - it's a hack.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: According to @fabian789 this method doesn't work. YMMV.

---

You could try calling

```
[myTextField setNeedsLayout];
[myTextField setNeedsRedraw];
```

to force it to redraw itself?

Disclaimer : This is just what I would try, I don't know if it will work!

Answer (score 0):

I also had to add/remove `inputAccessoryView` on text change so I ended up changing the `inputAccessoryView.alpha` value to make it look removed.

The animation is optional but it makes the transition look better:

**Swift 4**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
  myTextFieldOrTextView.inputAccessoryView?.alpha = 0      
}
```