# Best way to set up iphone forms?

Tags: iphone, forms, uitableview

What is the best way to code form views.  I'd like to use a UITableView but it's tedious wiring it up and modifying things.

Is there a best practice, or a particularly good framework for this type of task?

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202647/what-are-the-best-practices-for-implementing-form-in-ios

Comment: Yeah there are several questions but no definitive answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [QuickDialog](http://escoz.com/open-source/quickdialog). It is an open source library to build up forms. I think it is excellent and it will save you tons of time.