# Custom cells with textfield not being kept in memory in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create a registration form that contains around 20 different fields separated in four different sections.
I've created a custom cell for that, that contains a label and a UITextField and I've got an array of dictionaries on my tableview that indicates what the name of the label should be, as well as the tag of the texftield (because depending upon the tag I use a UIPicker to enter data).

The problem is that, when I start editing the fields, scrolling down and back up everything gets messed up, and changed on fields it should not... I've came across that this is obviously happening because I'm dequeing cells so it's creating duplicated references, so I tried to create a new cell every time, but that doesn't work since it will only initialize a tableview with the exact amount of cells I need but just blank cells with no content (label nor textfield) whatsoever inside.

What would be the easiest approach so I can keep a different memory reference for each one of my cells, considering the fact that I've got to retrieve their values when a button is pressed?

I've read the suggestions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202647/what-are-the-best-practices-for-implementing-form-in-ios) post but still have no idea about how to create an array of cells.

Any help?

This is the code for my definitions:

```
NSArray *section1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"100",@"tag",@"Title",@"title",@"title",@"fieldName",nil],
                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"tag",@"First Name",@"title",@"first_name",@"fieldName",nil],
                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"tag",@"Last Name",@"title",@"last_name",@"fieldName",nil],
                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"tag",@"Job Title",@"title",@"job_title",@"fieldName",nil],
                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"tag",@"Email",@"title",@"email",@"fieldName",nil],
                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"tag",@"Confirm Email",@"title",@"confirm_email",@"fieldName",nil],
                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"tag",@"Password",@"title",@"password",@"fieldName",nil],
                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"tag",@"Confirm Password",@"title",@"conf_password",@"fieldName",nil],
                     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"tag",@"Phone",@"title",@"phone",@"fieldName",nil],
                     nil];

....

self.formItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                  section1,
                  section2,
                  section3,
                  section4,
                  section5,
                  nil];
```

And then the code I use on cellForRowAtIndexPath is the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"freeTrialFormCell";
    TSIFreeTrialFormCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TSIFreeTrialFormCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSArray* sectionData = [self.formItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSDictionary* myFieldInfo = [sectionData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([[myFieldInfo objectForKey:@"fieldName"] rangeOfString:@"password"].location != NSNotFound) {
        cell.textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    }

    cell.fieldName = [myFieldInfo objectForKey:@"fieldName"];
    cell.textField.placeholder = [myFieldInfo objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.textField.tag = [[myFieldInfo objectForKey:@"tag"] integerValue];
    cell.label.text = [myFieldInfo objectForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention... I'm using StoryBoarding.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        TSIFreeTrialFormCell *cell = [[TSIFreeTrialFormCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];

    NSArray* sectionData = [self.formItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSDictionary* myFieldInfo = [sectionData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([[myFieldInfo objectForKey:@"fieldName"] rangeOfString:@"password"].location != NSNotFound) {
        cell.textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    }

    cell.fieldName = [myFieldInfo objectForKey:@"fieldName"];
    cell.textField.placeholder = [myFieldInfo objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.textField.tag = [[myFieldInfo objectForKey:@"tag"] integerValue];
    cell.label.text = [myFieldInfo objectForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;
}
```

But this will have a performance hit as you are creating cell for each row

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I mentioned this only creates a bunch of empty cells, with no label and no field. Do I need to do something else on my custom cell class?

Answer (score 0):

The UITableView reuses cells as you scroll up and down, so you will lose info that is only typed into that cell.  What I do is create an array to hold the inputs for those cells.

Basically:

```
enteredText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //iVar, not local variable
for (int i=0; i<numTableRows; i++) {
   [enteredText addObject:@""]; //fill with dummy values that you will replace as user types
}
```

Then in your table view text field, set yourself as the delegate of the text field and implement `textFieldDidEndEditing`.  In that method, replace the value in `enteredText`for that row with the user's text.

When you make the cell, set the text field text to the value of in your array:

```
myCell.textField.text = [enteredText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

It'll be blank at first, and then will hold the user's text after they've put something in there.

Comment: Souns like a good idea but wouldn't it be better to just not reuse cells, given it's not a really big number of cells? I'm already using my custom tableview controller class as the delegate so anyway it would not be that much of an effort to do this.